# FileNotFoundError when trying to save plot with plt.savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code. Python 3.11.5 from anaconda.

Latitude vs. Humidity

```
# Scatter plot for Latitude vs. Humidity
plt.scatter(city_data_df["Lat"], city_data_df["Humidity"], edgecolors="black", alpha=0.75)

# Add labels and title
plt.title("City Latitude vs. Humidity")
plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("Humidity (%)")

# Add grid
plt.grid(True)

# Save the figure
plt.savefig("output_data/Fig2.png")

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

This is the error

[image: This is the error]

My task is to make plots to showcase the relationship between weather variables and latitude.

I use the OpenWeatherMap API to retrieve weather data from the cities list generated in the started code.

Comment: you need to create the directory "output_data"

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you need to create the directory that you are saving the file into if it doesn't already exist as `savefig` won't create it. So, you could add in your code, e.g.,:

```
from pathlib import Path

# create the output directory if it doesn't exist
outputdir = Path("output_dir")
if not outputdir.is_dir():
    outputdir.mkdir()

# your code here
...

plt.savefig(outputdir / "Fig2.png")
```